# Can't find MPEG in the output settings

Tags: rendering, video, file-format

I am using the latest version 2.79 for windows, and I made a short video. Now I tried to render it as MPEG and it doesn't show up in the options and after a lot of research I can't find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 10):

In version 2.79 Video encoding settings have been simplified.
Read:https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features

Choose [FFmpeg video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) in the output panel.

A new set of options appear in the **Encoding** panel

There you can choose the flavor of Mpeg that you want to use:

[image]