# Video Codecs missing in Blender 2.79

Tags: rendering, video, encoding

Ever since I updated from Blender 2.77 to 2.79, my Codec menu in the Render tab looks like this:

[image: Very limited selection of video codecs].

I'd like to render a scene in H.264 and I have no idea why it is missing in the menu. This doesn't seem to be a common problem, I haven't found any forums threads about this issue at all. I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/cant-find-mpeg-in-the-output-settings/91246#91246