# How do I get H264 on my render formats?

Tags: rendering, video, file-format, encoding

[image: help]

I have used blender before, but h264 is not showing up

any way to get it on?

Comment: Please use search before asking https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/cant-find-mpeg-in-the-output-settings

Comment: Short answer: use ffmpeg (I think a better name would help most people to understand - most people doesn't understand what ffmpeg is or why should be their alternative in this menu, probably something like "encoded video" would be much more easy to choose)